# java replaceAll code to remove white spaces

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove the white space before these signs in the below code:

```
 != = < >
```

The output should be:

```
( name=john or  name=Robert ) and  salary!=10000 


class myPreg{
public static void main( String[] args ){

String s=" ( name = john or  name=Robert ) and  salary != 10000  ";

s= s.replaceAll( "[a-zA-Z0-9_]\\s+[!=|=|>|<]\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]", "[a-zA-Z0-9_][!=|=|>|<][a-zA-Z0-9_]" );

System.out.println(s);

} }// main class
```

Comment: Do you want to remove whitespace before, or before _and_ after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
String s = " ( name = john or  name=Robert ) and  salary != 10000  ";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+(!=|=|>|<)\\s+", "$1");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
 ( name=john or  name=Robert ) and  salary!=10000
```

If you also want to get rid of the trailing and leading whitespace, add a call to `trim()`.

Comment: Can you explain each part of the replaceAll function?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), the `replaceAll` method takes a regular exprression as first parameter and a string as second.

In your case, since you know what you want to match before hand, you can simply do as follows: `s = s.replaceAll("\\s+([=<>]|(!=))", "$1");`.

This will replace all white space followed by `=`, `<`, `>` or `!=` by the symbol itself. The `$1` has a special meaning in this case since it refers to the first group captured by the regular expression.

Since you seem to be after white spaces after as well, you can also use this: `s = s.replaceAll("\\s+([=<>]|(!=))\\s+", "$1");`.